# How to turn a shiny metallic surface into a matte surface?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

**How do I turn a glossy/shiny surface into a non-shiny or matte surface in Adobe Photoshop?**

I have here two images. The first is the image I would like to manipulate. The second image is the look I'm going for (not to replicate everything about it, but I want to achieve the same non-shiny look for the first image).

I'm aware that what I need to do is to dampen the highlights, and lower the contrast, but my attempts at adjusting the highlights via the `Shadows/Highlights...` menu and the contrast via the `Brightness/Contrast...` menu did not succeed. Adjusting colors by means of `Replace Color...` also did not yield success.

What other methods or techniques should I consider?

[image: Original shiny medal.]
[image: Goal matte medal.]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Applying a gradient map as a clipping mask should achieve something like the effect you're after. This quick gradient map:

[image]

Produced this:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Note, you are comparing a right-lit photo with a left-lit photo, so it's going to inherently appear different.

Sample a *mid-tone* from the image and then add a **Color Overlay Layer Style**. Set the overlay blend mode to **Darken** and reduce opacity until you are happy.

This will simply darken highlights creating a more matte finish.

[image]

From that point you can do some minor **Levels** or **Curves** adjustment to reduce *contrast* in the image and perhaps reduce the **Saturation** a bit via a **Hue/Saturation Adjustment layer**.

[image]